# Find a suitable linear transformation from $P_3$ to $P_3$ to get the solution of the differential equation $p''-2p'+p=x^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $P_3$ denote the real vector space of all the polynomials in one variable with the real coefficients and of degree less then or equal to $3$, equipped with the standard basis $\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Find a suitable linear transformation $T:P_3\to P_3$ to get a solution of the differential equation $p''-2p'+p=x^3$ and hence write a solution.

So that's the question is all about. Now I am confused whether I understood it correctly or not but I tried some thing with the idea in my head.

So the question required me to find a linear transformation $T$ such that it becomes a solution to the differential equation $p''-2p'+p=x^3$, that is the linear transform should satisfy the given differential equation. So the solution to the differential equation is the required transformation? Is it? But it has a problem, because the solution of the differential equation involves an exponential term, so we cannot really represent that term with the given basis. So this line of thought is not really working. How can I do this? Please help me out. thanks.

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096895/using-linear-transformations-to-solve-differential-equation?rq=1) might help.

Comment: Also, like you said, the exponential $e^{x}$ is a solution, though _only to the homogeneous problem_. So, in fact, is $xe^{x}$. But there is also a polynomial solution that corresponds to the _inhomogeneous_ problem, $p_{in} = 24 + 18x + 6x^{2} + x^{3}$.

Comment: Ok so according to the linked question, I should consider the homogeneous part of the differential equation as a linear transform and prove it to be so ?